# How can I create two column from one column/column header in Azure Data Factory Pipeline?

Tags: etl, azure-data-factory

I have daily autogenerating files in an onprem file. The file comes in with a "Net Sales 10/28/22" column header but I would like to create another column so there is two columns Net Sales and Net Sales Date. Also, when the new files for the next day is uploaded, I need that one column to be Net Sales and another column to be Net Sales Date. Here is what I am going for [image: OG File and Goal] Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is this different than your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74186045/how-can-i-pull-date-from-column-header-and-create-a-separate-column-for-it-in-az

Comment: In the answer provided for that question, the person who answered provided this expression for one of the derived columns: substring({Gross Margin 10/20/22}, instr({Gross Margin 10/20/22}, "")+0, 12) but this won't help me when the files after 10/20 get upload to the unprem files. So it won't pull 10/21, 10/22 to anything after that. I need a dynamic expression. Hopefully that made sense, please let me know if there is anything else I can clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure Data Factory, I created a dataflow. To get the date from the column header, I used two derived columns.

- I used the source dataset as a csv file. [image]
- Data preview of source:
  [image]
- Then I created one derived column using derived column activity to the source file named "columnames". In this column I am taking collection of all column's names in array. Using `columnNames()` Expression.
  [image]
- Data preview of derived column1:
  [image]
- Now, I have created another derived column activity to create two derived columns,

1. Net sales: In this column I am fetching values from `Net sales 10/28/2022` column of original dataset with `toInteger(byPosition(3))` expression this returns all values of column at position 3 in dataset
2. Net sales Date: In this column I am fetching date from `Net sales 10/28/2022` column header of original dataset with `at(columnnames,3)` this returns column name at index number 3 in columnnames array and `split(at(columnnames, 3),' ')[4]` expression splits the string with delimiter.
   [image]

- Data preview of derived column2 desired columns:
  [image]
- Now, select your desired columns from derived column 2 activity output.
  [image]
- **Data preview of select activity and desired output:**
  [image]

> when the new files for the next day is uploaded, I need that one column to be Net Sales and another column to be Net Sales Date.

When I uploaded another file with new date Got output in similar format. Sample file preview:
[image]
**Output for above file:**
[image]

Comment: This works perfect, thank you PratikLad. However, when I export the files there is no column header, how do I add the column header?

Comment: Create sink activity add dataset to it where you want to export it and if it is csv the check first row as header.

Comment: That's what I did but for Mapping in the sink it shows Input Columns (Store Number) to Output columns (Columns_1)

Comment: the file where you are exporting result there are no columns because of this you are seeing output columns as (Columns_1) to overcome this select **Auto mapping** under mapping

Comment: I selected auto mapping and it's still exporting the files without a column header

Comment: Here is a link to a google doc which will give you a better insight into the pipeline, it was created for your convenience so you can exactly see what is going on, if you would like: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10U64pjFgu117_p2GJWrhjXs1jDS5IRTPUc4oMKOdVso/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Never mind PratikLad, I didn't check "First Row as Header" in my ouput

Comment: how are you able to pull files with different dates? When I import a new file with a different date, it still only shows the date from the first file

Comment: I just added file with different dates in source dataset you can fetch files with help of get metadata activity and pass it to for each activity and dataflow to process files

Comment: I added get metadata and for each activity, running right now, will let you know if it works. Update: it worked, thank you!

Comment: Also, in your source it says you have 3 columns, mine says it has 0 columns. I can't import the projection because the columns are changing 11/2/22 then 11/3/22 the next day, so how are you able to show 3 columns in your source?

Comment: figure this out as well, thank you for the help @PratikLad